# Not able to detect the element and send input to the Credit Card Number field through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to automate a checkout process on [this website](http://www.converse.ca) . I am at the 4th stage where you click the "Credit Card" option in "Payment Information" and I am trying to `send_keys` to input in my credit card numbers.

However, I notice that after clicking the CC option, the page loads for a bit so I used an explicit wait for that element but that is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
ccNumber = session.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name=credit-card-number]')
wait = WebDriverWait(session, 100)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_selected(ccNumber))
```

This is the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[name=credit-card-number]"}
```

Comment: Try to define element as `ccNumber = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name=credit-card-number]")))`

Comment: @Andersson now the credit card button (input) is not even clicked, and it throws an error shortly after the webdriver finishes execution.
`raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)` from the line you advised above

Comment: as Anderson said, you need to wait BEFORE clicking the button, not after. Maybe his method is not right, but you have to find an element you can wait for and make it your criteria.

Comment: can you verify the css selector is correct? and finding the element in html

Comment: @KirilS. I have found out that the style attribute of the credit card div goes from `style="display: none` to nothing after the Credit Card button is pushed. Is it possible to use that criteria, and how?

Comment: removing `display:none` means element goes from invisible to visible, so you can try `visibility_of_element_located` condition. E.g. `ccNumber = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'credit-card-number')))`.

Comment: @KirilS. Thanks - although there is another thing I will need to wait for. The CC forms need to be loaded such that `<div id="credit-card-form" class="loading">` turns into `<div id="credit-card-form" class>`. What EC condition would this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<input>` field for the *Credit Card* number is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce WebDriverWait for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce WebDriverWait for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:
- Code Block:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(session, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"braintree-hosted-field-number")))
  WebDriverWait(session, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.number#credit-card-number"))).send_keys("0000000000000000")
  ```

Comment: Now I've gotten to the final step and clicked place order but it loads infinitely. Do you have any ideas why? Is it because of selenium as the browser instead of a regular one?

Comment: Done! Also would you have any idea why the payment step loads infinitely and doesn't complete? Are there any differences between chrome driver and chrome that might have caused this? There should have been a popup saying card is invalid

Comment: Which exact step as in _payment step_ causes this issue? Payment Submission?

Comment: The very last button. In "6 - order review". Upon an invalid payment submission, a pop up should come up indicating that the payment did not go through

Comment: Seems additional steps are needed.Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please?

Comment: [Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676925/chrome-webdriver-unable-to-complete-product-checkout-automation)

Answer (score 0):

You could wait until the Loading spinner no longer appears on the page anymore before checking for the credit card input.  We have a C# solution that you could try to adapt to python where you wait in a loop for an element to be displayed, catching the exceptions until reaching the timeout.

```
    //Assert an element is displayed before the timeout milliseconds run out.
    public void AssertElementIsDisplayed(int timeout, IWebElement element, string elementName = "element")
    {
        Action<IWebElement> target = delegate (IWebElement e) {
            if (e == null)
            {
                throw new AssertionException("Failed to find " + elementName + ". It is null");
            }
            if (!e.Displayed)
            {
                elementName = (elementName == "element" && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.GetAttribute("title"))) ? e.GetAttribute("title") : elementName;
                throw new AssertionException("Expected (" + elementName + ") to be displayed but it was not");
            }
        };
        AssertInLoop(element, (long)timeout, 100L, target);
    }

    //Assert some Action on a WebElement for as long as the timeoutMillis allow.
    private void AssertInLoop(IWebElement element, long timeoutMillis, long millisBetweenAttempts, Action<IWebElement> callable)
    {
        AssertionException lastAssertionError = null;
        WebDriverException lastWebDriverException = null;

        long startTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
        if (timeoutMillis < 500 || timeoutMillis > 120 * 1000)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Timeout outside expected range. timeout_millis=" + timeoutMillis);
        }

        long millisLeft = timeoutMillis;

        while (millisLeft >= 1)
        {
            long lastAttemptStartMillis = DateTimeOffset.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
            try
            {
                callable(element);
                return;
            }
            catch (AssertionException e)
            {
                lastAssertionError = e;
                lastWebDriverException = null;
            }
            catch (StaleElementReferenceException e)
            {
                lastAssertionError = null;
                lastWebDriverException = e;
            }
            catch (NotFoundException e)
            {
                lastAssertionError = null;
                lastWebDriverException = e;
            }
            catch (SystemException e)
            {
                throw e;
            }


            long elapsedMillis = (DateTimeOffset.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond) - startTime;
            millisLeft = timeoutMillis - elapsedMillis;

            if (millisLeft >= 1)
            {
                long millisElapsedDuringThisAttempt = (DateTimeOffset.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond) - lastAttemptStartMillis;
                long millisToSleep = millisBetweenAttempts - millisElapsedDuringThisAttempt;
                if (millisToSleep > 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep((int)millisToSleep);
                }
            }
        }

        if (lastAssertionError != null)
        {
            throw lastAssertionError;
        }
        else if (lastWebDriverException != null)
        {
            throw lastWebDriverException;
        }
    }
```